# Using SORT in JCL, require only a maximum count after counting records group by

Tags: mainframe, dfsort, syncsort

I have a problem, in which I need the **max count** after performing the **group by count of records** from position 1 to length 5, in a single step using **SORT in JCL**.

Tried with below **JCL** code, and was able to perform the group by count of records, but now only max count record is require, and tried MAX, but for every usage job abends.

Sample Data:

```
    AAAAA 234
    AAAAA 124
    BBBBB 324
    BBBBB 546
    AAAAA 325
    CCCCC 754
    BBBBB 546
    BBBBB 346
    CCCCC 765
```

SORT Control statement used in JCL Step:

```
    SORT FIELDS=(1,5,CH,A)
    OUTFIL REMOVECC,NODETAIL,
    SECTIONS=(1,5,TRAILER3=(1,5,X,COUNT=(M10,LENGHT=4)))
```

Current output:

```
    AAAAA 3
    BBBBB 4
    CCCCC 2
```

Require output:

```
    BBBBB 4
```

Could anyone please help and suggest how I can use MAX along with SECTIONS, TRAILER and COUNT in single step.

Comment: Really, JCL has nothing to do with this - and you have not shown any. You have shown sort control statements, which are not JCL.

Comment: @NicC I thought JCL statements are not that important to mention here, as main logic lies in SORT statements only and JCL step only have EXEC, SORTIN and SORTOUT.

Comment: Solution:

        SORT FIELDS=(1,5,CH,A)
        OUTREC OVERLAY=(8:X,9:SEQNUM,4,ZD,RESTART=(1,5))
        OUTFIL REMOVECC,NODETAIL,
        TRAILER1=(1:MAX=(9,4,ZD,M11))

This solution is not complete, but complte enough for my requirement.